# File extension for Gimp's Python-fu scripts and installation of them

Tags: gimp

I created some files for Python-fu codes I found in internet in Gimp scripts folder, naming them as *.pyscript. Is it right?

I don't know if they are already installed or if I have to execute them once to install them. Also I don't see any changes in Gimp menus, as expected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i dont know whether its useful or not for you but have a look, who knows you get a clue on the fly...

- [script fu and python fu](http://registry.gimp.org/node/24829)
- [Python-fu](http://zwell.net/content/pygimp.html)
- [GIMP/Installing Plugins](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GIMP/Installing_Plugins)
- [How to Use Script-Fu and Python-Fu for GIMP](http://www.ehow.com/how_5715564_use-script-fu-python-fu-gimp.html)
- [PyGimp Plugin Collection](http://python-fu.sourceforge.net/)
- [Python Fu Scripts - HowDoI Install?](http://registry.gimp.org/node/19901)
- [Installing GIMP Scripts](http://gimptips.com/articles/installing-gimp-scripts)
- [Scripts that work in GIMP-2.6+](http://www.gimphelp.org/script24.shtml)

Sorry if you don't find this answers useful :|

Comment: 50% of the links now show you, why link only answers are a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

To make it work in linux (I'm on Ubuntu):

1. the correct extension is .py - its a Python script after all
2. put it into $HOME/.gimp-2.x/plug-ins folder
3. change it to executable (chmod +x script.py)
4. restart Gimp

Also re-check if you registered the script correctly.
Source should be something like this:

```
from gimpfu import *

def my_filter_function(timg,tlayer):
  ... do your work here ...

register(
  "my_script_name",
  "Script blurb",
  "Script help",
  "Author name",
  "Copyright information",
  "2011",
  "<Image>/Filters/Menu item/&Where it will appear",
  "RGB*, GRAY*",
  [],[],
  my_filter_function
)
```

*register* function information is also available from script-fu console - type this in:

```
>>> from gimpfu import *; help(register)
Help on function register in module gimpfu:

register(proc_name, blurb, help, author, copyright, date, label, imagetypes, params, results, function, menu=None, domain=None, on_query=None, on_run=None)
    This is called to register a new plug-in.
```